# Tags [pipe] and [pipes] should be synonyms

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

I happened to spot that I've got bronze topic badges for both [pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pipe) and [pipes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pipes).  Unfortunately, there are 1154 questions tagged [pipes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pipes) and 2358 questions tagged [pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pipe), and 49 questions tagged with both, which makes any manual retagging exercise moderately silly.  The wiki entries for the tags are clearly describing the same things.

The plural tag [pipes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pipes) should be a synonym of tag [pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pipe).

The problem has been spotted by other people before: there are now 4 votes towards making [pipes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pipes) a synonym of [pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pipe).

Please contribute the final vote at https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pipe/synonyms if you can.

Comment: It's [meta-tag:status-completed], though it wasn't me. BTW: The synonym-pages say it was 11 months in the making...

Comment: Now we have [tag:piping], maybe should merge into [tag:pipe] ?

Comment: @zx8754 — Ugh!  Yes, [tag:piping] should be a synonym of [tag:pipe].  It's funny — I've answered the most questions (8) of the top scorers, without ever noticing the tag.  Someone else managed to get far more points than me, but on a single question.  I've created a synonym proposal at [pipe synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pipe/synonyms); now to get people to vote on it.

Comment: See the new (April 2018) question [Tag pipe and piping should be synonyms](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366608/tags-pipe-and-piping-should-be-synonyms) — and please up-vote the synonym proposal if you can.

Comment: There is also [tag:pipeline], which contains a lot of questions about piping/pipes.

Comment: @VadimKotov: I think the [tag:pipeline] tag is more complex to deal with.  It has uses outside of the traditional "Unix shell pipeline" meaning, and some of the questions tagged with it should not simply be retagged as "pipe".  There are some 1728 questions when I typed this.  I'm sure there are some which are simple "pipe" questions, but it is by no means all of them.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yeah, that true, that's only a small portion of them. I do not assume that all these questions are about pipes

Comment: @VadimKotov: I've updated the tag info (long and short forms) to suggest "use [tag:pipe] for questions about shell pipelines".  Of course, it will still not be noticed by many people who mistag questions with [tag:pipeline].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tag [pipes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pipes) is now a synonym of [pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pipe).

This answer allows the question to be closed with an accepted answer.