# Tags [pipe] and [piping] should be synonyms

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

This is closely related to the question [Tags [pipe] and [pipes] should be synonyms](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/273257/tags-pipe-and-pipes-should-be-synonyms), which has been resolved since October 2011 — those two tags are synonyms.

However, there is another closely related tag, [piping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/piping), that should also be a synonym of [pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pipe).  There are about 347 questions with the tag [piping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/piping) (compared with 6,370 with the tag [pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pipe)).  Many of the top users have only answered one question in the tag — I've answered 8, it seems, but I wasn't even aware of the tag's existence until someone pointed it out to me.

I've created a **[synonym proposal that [piping] should be a synonym of [pipe]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pipe/synonyms)**.  Please cast your votes in favour.

Comment: We need 2 more votes on this -- https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pipe/synonyms

Comment: @VadimKotov ain't got no time for that. ;p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with the premise that [pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pipe) and [piping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/piping) should be synonyms. The tag excerpts also suggest that they mean the same thing:

> A Unix pipe connects file descriptors of two processes. A pipe is created with the POSIX pipe() function declared in . Shells provide pipe creation between processes using "|". Pipes can also be created on Windows with CreatePipe(). This concept is available for portably redirecting standard input, standard output, and standard error into the calling process in .net and Java langauges.

and

> This tag is appropriate for questions related to taking output from one operation and using it as input to a subsequent operation.

The tag wikis are also very similar. I have approved the synonym, and now they are synonyms.